# Let $f $ be differentiable function, and assume $\lim_{x \to \infty}f'=L$ exists and $\{f(n)\}_1^\infty$ converges, then $L=0$

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

Let $f $ be differentiable function, and assume $\lim_{x \to \infty}f'=L$ exists and $\{f(n)\}_1^\infty$ converges, then $L=0$

Here is my proof:
Assume WLOG $L \geq 0$

Let $n$ be an natural number s.t if $x>n$ then $f'(x)\geq\frac{L}{2}$. Now by MVT we know that $f(n+1)-f(n)\geq \frac{L}{2}$ Now this is a telescoping series so it should converge if $f(n)$ converges. But in this case clearly the series converges unless $L=0$ and so we are done.

Is this correct? Is there a nice different proof?

Comment: How can we say  there is such natural number $n$? Are you also assuming that $f'$ is positive?

Comment: @LevBahn Since the derivative converges to $L$ so choose $\epsilon<\frac{L}{2}$, I am not assuming it is positive. I am assuming eventually it is (WLOG)

Comment: The key is to use mean value theorem. $f(n+1)-f(n)=f'(\xi)\to L$ hence $L=0$. There was no need for $L/2$ stuff although your approach is correct if $L>0$.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh That is exactly what i wrote, no?

Comment: I edited my comments to approve your approach.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh Is it not a formal way of saying what you said? I had the idea you had but I need to be as formal as possible. if $L<0$ same proof follows.

Comment: No my approach is bit different in the sense it is direct and does not use contradiction. Also the insistence should be on rigor and not formalism.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\varepsilon>0$ be arbitrary. Then there exists $N_{1}\in\mathbb{N}$
such that $|f'(x)-L|<\varepsilon$ whenever $x\geq N_{1}$. Observe
that $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\left[f(n+1)-f(n)\right]=\lim_{n}f(n+1)-\lim_{n}f(n)=0$,
so there exists $N_{2}\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $|f(n+1)-f(n)|<\varepsilon$
whenever $n\geq N_{2}$. Choose $n_0>\max(N_{1},N_{2})$, then there
exists $\xi\in(n_0,n_0+1)$ such that $f(n_0+1)-f(n_0)=f'(\xi)$. Note that $\xi\geq N_1$. Now, we
have estimation: 
\begin{eqnarray*}
 &  & |L|\\
 & \leq & |L-f'(\xi)|+|f'(\xi)|\\
 & = & |L-f'(\xi)|+|f(n_0+1)-f(n_0)|\\
 & < & \varepsilon+\varepsilon.
\end{eqnarray*}
It follows that $L=0$.